# What happened to those whose tombs were open?

Tags: catholicism, resurrection-body

in Matthew 27:52-53

> tombs were opened, and the bodies of many saints who had fallen asleep
> were raised. And coming forth from their tombs after his resurrection,
> they entered the holy city and appeared to many. [Source](https://bible.usccb.org/bible/matthew/27)

Is there any teaching or opinions on what happened to these saints after they appeared to many? Did they literally raised from the dead with their body or did they appear only as spirits? Did their body go back to the tombs afterwards or were assumed? What is the catholic belief?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cornelius à Lapide's commentary on Matthew](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3845) 27:52:

> Did, then, these saints die again after their resurrection, or continue in life and glory? Some think they did die, and are to rise again at the last day, and this from S. Paul’s words, “That they without us should not be made perfect.” [[Heb. 11:40](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=65&ch=11&l=40-#x)] (See S. Augustine, *Epist.* xcix. *ad Evodium*.) Others suppose, and more correctly, that they died no more, but were raised up to life immortal. Because it was but fitting that Christ should manifest at once in their resurrection the power of His own. It was also meet that happy souls like these should be united only to glorious and immortal bodies. But their happiness would have been but brief, and their misery greater, if they had died again so speedily. It would have been better, indeed, if they had not risen at all. It was also but fitting that they should adorn Christ’s triumphant ascension, as captives redeemed by Him, and the spoils He had won from death; and, lastly, that He should have them with Him in Heaven, and that His human nature, enjoying their presence and society, might never be solitary and void of human consolation. So Origen, S. Jerome, S. Clemens Alex. (*Strom. lib.* vi.), and others. The words “without us” do not refer to the day of judgment, but to the resurrection of Christ and Christians. (See notes on [Heb. 11:40](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=65&ch=11&l=40-#x).)

Comment: What of Lazarus?  Was he also raised up to immortal life right then?

Comment: @MikeBorden [St. Thomas's commentary on St. Matthew's gospel](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5049) mentions Lazarus:

Comment: @MikeBorden "Concerning these bodies of the saints, the question is usually raised, whether or not they were going to die again. It is undisputed that some men rose again, after they had died, such as **Lazarus**. But concerning these men it can be said that they rose so as not to die again, because they rose for the showing of Christ’s Resurrection. Now it is certain that Christ rising from the dead will now die no more. Likewise, if they had risen, it would not have been beneficial for them, but rather detrimental; wherefore, they rose as being about to go with Christ into heaven."